# Mitmproxy use dynamic ip address for --mode upstream:https://ip:port

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, mitmproxy

I want to use upstream proxy mode, but the parameter must specify `--mode`, as follows

```
mitmweb --mode upstream:https://x.x.x.x:8888/ -s test.py
```

But my proxy is dynamic, it expires after a few hours, there is no fixed IP.
How should I write so that I can get it dynamically instead of specifying upstream in the startup command:

**Code of `test.py`:**

```
class Counter:
    last_time = time.time()
    cache_time = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.proxy_list = Dbdriver().get_proxy_list()

    def update_proxy_list(self):
        if time.time() - self.last_time > self.cache_time:
            self.proxy_list = Dbdriver().get_proxy_list()
            self.last_time = time.time()

    def request(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        if flow.request.method == "CONNECT":
            return

        if flow.live:
            self.update_proxy_list()
            ctx.log.info(flow.request.url)
            proxy_dict = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
            proxy = (proxy_dict['ip'], proxy_dict['port'])
            flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)

addons = [
    Counter()
]
```